# WebForms Model Binding: Automatically map updated values to Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, model-binding

I'm currently working on a little dummy application to get my head around the new (awesome) model binding in WebForms. I've succesfully listed data both in a ListView and a FormView, however I'm stuck on updating the data.

I have a very simple FormView control:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="formViewOrderDetail" 
    ItemType="ModelBindingDummy.Models.Order" DataKeyNames="Id"
    SelectMethod="GetOrder" UpdateMethod="UpdateOrder">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p>Supplier Order Number: <%#: Item.SupplierOrderNumber %></p>
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Edit" runat="server" ID="linkEdit"
                        CommandName="Edit" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <p>Supplier Order Number: 
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="SupplierOrderNumber" 
                         Text='<%#: Item.SupplierOrderNumber %>' />
         </p>
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Save" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

My `UpdateOrder` method looks like this:

```
public void UpdateOrder(int id)
{
    ModelBindingDummy.Models.Order item = GetOrder(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Item with id {0} was not found", id));
        return;
    }            
    TryUpdateModel(item);

    //All data in the app is in-memory, so no need to actually update
    //the item as it is only a reference
}
```

Now my problem is that the TryUpdateModel doesn't work. It simply ignores the value in the TextBox `SupplierOrderNumber`

I've tried adding a parameter to the update method, `[Control] string supplierOrderNumber`, and while that works, I'd really like to see a way to automatically map that value.

I've also seen solutions using the `<asp:DynamicEntity />` control, but that seems somewhat overkill.

So my question is: Is it possible to get the `TryUpdateModel` method to map the TextBox value, or do I need to go all the way with the `DynamicEntities` control, or are there any other fancy solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `BindItem.SupplierOrderNumber` instead of `Item.SupplierOrderNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DataItem.SupplierOrderNumber instead of Item.SupplierOrderNumber

There is another question like this out there with a better explanation but i can't find it.